# How can I write a C function to translate an integer to an English phrase?

Tags: c

While I've done tons of Java programming, I'm new to C.

I'm using **int**s to store a designation code for a deck of playing cards from 1 to 52, e.g. 1 is the Ace of Hearts, 15 is the Two of Diamonds, etc. For display purposes, I want to translate these into English phrases, i.e. pass in 1 and return "Ace of Hearts". I'm having lots of trouble defining a function and a call to that function that my compiler will accept.

I know that strings are problematic in C, at least for people who haven't already done a lot of it. I understand pointers and their operators but haven't had much practice using them in programs.

I'm using MS VisualStudio 2019 with the NVidia CUDA toolkit. I've searched Web forums for similar situations, and I've written code that looks like it should work but the compiler rejects it every time.

```
void main() {
     ...
    char descriptor[14];
    designationTranslator(1, descriptor);
}

void designationTranslator(int cardDesignation, char* desc ) {

    switch (cardDesignation) {

    case 1:  strcpy(desc, "Ace of Hearts");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

This is only one of many, many versions of the same basic code that I've tried, and none will pass validation. I've added and removed * and & every place I could, used different variable declarations, etc. and nothing works. I just get a "Cannot find designationTranslator" error no matter how I write the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to call `designationTranslator` before you define it.

You need to either *declare* `designationTranslator` before you call it or move the definition of `designationTranslator` before `main`.

So either this:

```
void designationTranslator(int cardDesignation, char* desc );

int main()
{
    ...
}

void designationTranslator(int cardDesignation, char* desc )
{
    ...
}
```

Or this:

```
void designationTranslator(int cardDesignation, char* desc )
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, back to Programming 101 for me! Thanks very much for taking the time to help the clueless!